# Efficient Django full-text search without Haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

What's the next best option for database-agnostic full-text search for Django without Haystack?

I have a model like:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PaperReview(models.Model):
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I need to search for papers by title and reviewer name, but I also want to search from the perspective of a person and find which papers they have and haven't reviewed. With Haystack, it's trivial to implement a full-text index to search by title and name fields, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to do the "left outer join" necessary to find papers without a review by a specific person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [djorm-ext-pgfulltext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djorm-ext-pgfulltext), which provides a simple Django interface for PostgreSQL's built-in full text search features.

Answer (score 1):

Haystack is just a wrapper that exposes a few different search engine backends:

- Solr
- ElasticSearch
- Whoosh
- Xapian

There might be other backends as well available as plugins.

So the real question here is, is there a search backend that gives me the desired functionality, and does haystack expose that functionality?

The answer to that is, you can probably use elasticsearch*, but note the asterix.

Generally, when creating a search index, it's a good idea to think about the documents in the same way you might if you were creating a no-rel database and you want those documents to be as flat as possible.

So one possibility might be to have an array of char fields on a paperreview index. The array would contain all of the related foreign key references.

Another might be to use "nested documents" in elasticsearch.

And lastly, to use "parent/child documents" in elasticsearch.

You can still use haystack for indexing, with some hacking, but you will probably want to use one of the raw backends directly, such as pyelasticsearch or pyes.

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field/
- http://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I think my more general point is the type of search I'm doing is inherently unsuitable to the type of search functionality Haystack wraps. Probably indexed SQL tables handle left outer joins very efficiently, and even handle full text search well in some cases. I've tried Whoosh (horrible), Solr and ElasticSearch, and none handle this specific case very well.

Comment: @Cerin Did you read my above comments about parent/child documents in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is older, but I spent some time investigation this recently and answered this as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582377/django-text-search-haystack-vs-postgres-full-text-search/49246738#49246738) but it is actually not too hard to implement this yourself, and wanted to share.

I found the [SearchVector/SearchQuery approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) actually does not catch all cases, for example partial words (see https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/partial-word-search-with-postgres-full-text-search-in-django/632/ for reference). You can implement your own without much trouble, depending on your constraints. 
example, within a viewsets' get_queryset method:

```
    ...other params...

            search_terms = self.request.GET.get('q')
            if search_terms:
                # remove possible other delimiters and other chars
                # that could interfere
                cleaned_terms = re.sub(r'[!\'()|&;,]', ' ', search_terms).strip()
                if cleaned_terms:
                    # Check against all the params we want
                    # apply to previous terms' filtered results
                    q = reduce(
                        lambda p, n: p & n,
                        map(
                            lambda word:
                                Q(your_property__icontains=word) | Q(
                                    second_property__icontains=word) | Q(
                                    third_property__icontains=word)
                            cleaned_terms.split()
                        )
                    )
                    qs = YourModel.objects.filter(q)
           return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Haystack + elastic search and so far its working pretty well. Dont think its trivial . You can easily implement your requirement, if theres a association between paper and person.